# Unix: Grabbing dates from file and sorting them

Tags: unix, awk

I have multiple files that look like this:

```
//file start
$thing1 = {'item1' => '0', 'item2 => '3', 'itemDate' => '2013-10-01'};
$thing2 = {'item1' => '0', 'item2 => '3', 'itemDate' => '2012-11-01'};
$thing3 = {'item1' => '0', 'item2 => '3', 'itemDate' => '2014-12-01'};
//file end
```

Using Unix, what is the best way to grab all of the items in a file that are dates. I know that the items I'm looking for in the file look like

```
{somethingDate = '1111-11-11'}
```

From this I want to grab '1111-11'11'. File one will have multiple 'fileOneDate' entries and file two will have multiple 'fileTwoDate' entries, etc. My goal is to take all of these dates that are '*Date', remove duplicates, and sort them into an output file, which is easy enough using the sort command and pipes. However, I'm stuck on this first part. What I have so far looks like this:

```
<command I'm working on now that grabs dates> | sort -n  > outputfile.txt
```

I believe the way to go would be an AWK script. What would be the right way to parse these files?

Answer (score 1):

Do you need like this?

```
sed -n "s/.*'\([0-9]\{4\}-[0-9]\{2\}-[0-9]\{2\}\)'.*/\1/p"
```

If you have `-r` option in `sed`,

```
sed -nr "s/.*'([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2})'.*/\1/p"
```

**Test:**

```
sat:~# echo "{somethingDate = '1111-11-11'}" | sed -n "s/.*'\([0-9]\{4\}-[0-9]\{2\}-[0-9]\{2\}\)'.*/\1/p"
1111-11-11
sat:~#
sat:~# echo "$thing1 = {'item1' => '0', 'item2 => '3', 'itemDate' => '2013-10-01'};" | sed -n "s/.*'\([0-9]\{4\}-[0-9]\{2\}-[0-9]\{2\}\)'.*/\1/p"
2013-10-01
```

Comment: If you use the `r` option, you do not need to escape the `()` like this: `sed -nr "s/.*'([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2})'.*/\1/p"`

Answer (score 1):

`grep -o` is the simplest way to extract text.
`sort -u` to sort (duh) and remove duplicates.

```
grep -oE '\<[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}\>' <<'END' | sort -u
$thing1 = {'item1' => '0', 'item2 => '3', 'itemDate' => '2013-10-01'};
$thing2 = {'item1' => '0', 'item2 => '3', 'itemDate' => '2012-11-01'};
$thing3 = {'item1' => '0', 'item2 => '3', 'itemDate' => '2014-12-01'};
$thing2b= {'item1' => '0', 'item2 => '3', 'itemDate' => '2012-11-01'};
$thing2c= {'item1' => '0', 'item2 => '3', 'itemDate' => 'foo2012-01-01bar'};
END
```

```
2012-11-01
2013-10-01
2014-12-01
```

Comment: The `-o` option is available in GNU `grep` and BSD (Mac OS X) `grep`, but not defined by POSIX.  Depending on the Unix platform, therefore, it may or may not be available.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, Jonathan. Fortunately busybox grep has that option.

Answer (score 0):

If your sample file is called `datefile`, then:

```
$ sed -nr "s/.*Date' => '([^']+)'.*/\1/p" datefile | sort -n
2012-11-01
2013-10-01
2014-12-01
```

The above regex looks for lines containing `Date' => 'datestring'` and prints the datestring.

In more detail, the `sed` command consists of a substitution which, in `sed`-style, are written as `s/old/new/options`.  The `old` part is a bit complicated so I will go through it piece by piece: the `old` regex looks for (a) `.*` means anything (any number of any characters), followed by (b) `Date' => '`, followed by (c) `([^']+)` which means one or more characters that are not single quotes, followed by (d) a single quote, followed by (e) `.*`, again meaning anything.  If a match is made, then that line is replaced with the date string (saved as `\1` because the date string regex was in parens) and then, because of the `p` at the end of the expression, that date is printed.  Because the `-n` option is given to `sed`, lines with no matching datestring are not printed.

If your `sed` does not support `-r` (OSX), then use a similar expression but with a few added backslashes:

```
sed -n "s/.*Date' => '\([^']\+\)'.*/\1/p" datefile | sort -n
```

Comment: Note that Mac OS X `sed` supports `-E` for extended regular expressions (instead of `-r`).